# Off Site AD Authentication

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a web application (not production) for which I want to enable AD authentication. The problem is that the DC is not mine, it is the client's. The site will be hosted remotely (amazon, rackspace or some other host). Can I enable the client's users to authenticate with their domain user?

They should be able to use the windows login credentials and if possible even input their user-password when accessing the application.

I have maxed my googling skills on that one.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your target programming language? If your server is not part of the infrastructure, you cannot use Kerberos. If you cannot use Kerberos you have to resort to unsecure NTLM *or* use secure Digest MD5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this requires opening LDAPS on firewalls and securing it to a set of source IPs, generally. That's really not a great design and many companies (rightly) won't allow this. What you really want to look in to is federation ala Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) or similiar.

Comment: I will definitely look into that. It seems to be exactly what I need. Thank You!